# Como salir de un bucle FOR interno para volver al externo

Tags: java

No sé si se entendió mi pregunta.
Lo que quiero lograr es imprimir en pantalla esto:

Alumno: Pedro Nota: 8........ 
Alumno: Ciro Nota 5

Mi logica era salir del bucle interno, pero debe haber otra solución. Alguna ayuda?
Recien estoy aprendiendo, quizás no sea la mejor manera de hacerlo.

```
for(int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {

        System.out.print("Alumno: " +alumnos[i]);

            for (int j=0; j < notas.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(" Nota: " +notas[j]);


            }
            System.out.println();
        } 



    }
```

Comment: ¿Un alumno tiene diferentes notas? o simplemente una nota por alumno.

Comment: Si una nota por alumno

Comment: Lo que hace tu código actualmente es que por cada alumno muestra todas las notas que tengas almacenadas. Es decir, todos los alumnos tendrán las mismas notas. No creo que sea eso lo que buscas.

Comment: Claro, e estado probando con los controles de flujo, pero no da resultado.

En pantalla me imprime asi:

Alumno: ivan Nota: 5 Nota: 8 ..........
Alumno: asd Nota: 5 Nota: 8 

Pero no es lo que yo quiero, lo que quiero es que salga así:

Alumno: ivan Nota: 5 .........
Alumno: asd Nota: 5

Comment: ¿Los dos `array` tienen la misma dimensión?

Comment: Si! porque seria una nota por alumno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for(int i=0;i<alumnos.lenght;i++){

       System.out.println("Alumno: " + alumnos[i] + "Nota: " + notas[i]);
       System.out.println("");
    }
```

Con esto asignas valor a valor. Es decir, el alumno en la posición 0 tendrá la nota de la posición 0 y así... hasta terminar el `array`.

Comment: Excelente, era tan sencillo pero me a tenido pensando toda la tarde, muchas gracias!

Comment: Si te solucionó el problema, no olvides marcar la respuesta como valida. Un saludo.